# Reading from C socket, can't print buffer directly

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm reading from a socket and trying to print the results.

```
    char readBuffer[1024] = {0};
    int amntRead;
    amntRead = read(new_socket, readBuffer, 1024-1);
```

If I try

```
    printf("read: %s\n", readBuffer);
```

a lot of blank space gets printed, but if I do

```
for(int i = 0; i < amntRead; ++i)
    {
        if(isalpha(readBuffer[i]) || isdigit(readBuffer[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", readBuffer[i]);

        }
    }
```

All the characters of interest appear.

I tried adding `isspace` to the conditional above, but gives me mostly blank space again. What exactly is going on? I am assuming it's like a unicode or UTF-8 issue.

Comment: What are you sending to that socket? That's what you're getting out.

Comment: What are the bytes that you skip in the printing loop?  Add `else printf("[%d]", readbuffer[i]);` or something similar so you see the character codes that you're skipping.

Comment: Use `fwrite()` to print just the number of bytes read

Comment: `printf(“read: %.*s\n”, amntRead, readBuffer);`.

Comment: The question you should ask is why the buffer contains whitespace.  That is not revealed by the information in your question, but almost certainly that is what the sender sent.  Are you sure this is text data and not binary?  Inspect the buffer in your debugger to see _exactly_ what it contains.

Comment: @user207421, given that the buffer is zero initialised that should not be necessary (if this is actually text and not binary data, in which case `%s` would be inappropriate).

Comment: @Clifford The error here consists of ignoring the length returned by `read()`. That’s just an example of how not to do so.

Comment: @user207421 if you believe that, explain the reported output.  The buffer is pre-initialised to nul (1024 nuls), no more than 1023 characters are read.  The read data _must_ be null terminated.  The whitespace is either in the data, or the code fragments in the question omit vital information.  You see code that does not follow your expected idiom and assume that is the problem, but it does not match the facts presented.   It may or may not be a bad idea, but it is not on the available information an explanation of the output.

Comment: Is the whitespace before, after or interspersed with the expected data.  Others seem to think you are simply outputting an unterminated string, which is not wholly supported by what you have posted.  Your description of the output is too vague, and could clear up that debate if clarified.

Comment: "_I am assuming it's like a unicode or UTF-8 issue._." is the data UTF-8?  If it were I would not expect the reported output for codes below 128. You really need to be explicit about the actual content of the buffer.  You really should have an accurate idea of what this data is and it's format/encoding before you attempt to process it.  I suspect the issue is the data is simply not text string data as you assume.

Comment: @Clifford The buffer is pre-initialized to *one* null according to my reading of the C++ specification. If if was initialized to 1024 nulls there would have to be 1024 initialization values.

Comment: @user207421, no when an array has an initialiser of any length, the remainder of the array is zero initialised. And this is a C question, not C++ (even though the behaviour is common).

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C are null terminated. It means a string is considered finished when '\0' (ascii code = 0) also called null character appears.
The code

```
printf("read: %s\n", readBuffer);
```

prints until first null character in `readBuffer` appears.

Your for loops uses precise length and stops.

---

Even though your buffer is zero initialized, it is being modified by `read`. Add following line before `printf`

```
readBuffer[amntRead] = 0;
```

Comment: But the buffer is zero initialised, so it seems that is not the issue.  In the for loop whitespace (and anything not alpha numeric) is discarded.  The simple fact is that the buffer contains whitespace.  The reason for that is not revealed by the information in the question.